# How to force Spark/Hive to create task_* directories with custom permissions

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, filesystems, user-permissions, hive-metastore

I have the following problem. I will try to give as much details as possible, but if I miss anything that maybe useful to get this working, do not hesitate to ask.

```
# spark-defaults:
spark.sql.warehouse.dir = /mnt/data
spark.hadoop.fs.permissions.umask-mode = 007

# hive-site:
<property>
  <name>hive.warehouse.subdir.inherit.perms</name>
  <value>true</value>
  <description></description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.execute.setugi</name>
  <value>true</value>
  <description></description>
</property>
```

I tried playing with the above hive-site settings with different combinations of those two, but the issue still persists.

Spark cluster (standalone, master/workers/shuffle/thrift/history) is running as user **spark** (service account) and it is part of **spark users** group. No HDFS, but the filesystem is distributed and posix compliant (think of it as commercial HDFS), NFS v3 mounted. Hive metastore is in PostgreSQL 10.

Spark Warehouse is here:

```
# ls -l /mnt
drwxrws--- 22 spark spark users 10240 Aug  9 09:31 data

# umask
0007
```

I run PySpark process as a **user_1** that is part of **spark users** group. The process creates database, creates table and writes data into the table.

The process fails with the following exceptions:

```
18/08/09 09:31:42 ERROR FileFormatWriter: Aborting job null.
java.io.IOException: Failed to rename 
DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus
{path=file:/mnt/data/new.db/new_table/_temporary/0/ 
task_20180809093142_0002_m_000000/
part-00000-55f3fe5c-51c2-4a0f-9f0c-dc673f9967b3-c000.snappy.parquet;
isDirectory=false; length=39330; replication=1; blocksize=33554432; 
modification_time=1533821502000; access_time=0; owner=; group=; 
permission=rw-rw-rw-; isSymlink=false} to 
file:/mnt/data/new.db/new_table/
part-00000-55f3fe5c-51c2-4a0f-9f0c-dc673f9967b3-c000.snappy.parquet
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.mergePaths
(FileOutputCommitter.java:415) at 
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.mergePaths
(FileOutputCommitter.java:428) at 
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJobInternal
(FileOutputCommitter.java:362) at 
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJob
(FileOutputCommitter.java:334) at 
org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputCommitter.commitJob
(ParquetOutputCommitter.java:47) at 
org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitJob
(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:166) at 
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write
(FileFormatWriter.scala:213) at 
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand
.run (InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:154) at 
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec
.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104) at 
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec
.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102) at 
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec
.executeCollect(commands.scala:115) at 
org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$6.apply
(Dataset.scala:190) at 
org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$6.apply
(Dataset.scala:190) at 
org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply
(Dataset.scala:3254) at 
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId
(SQLExecution.scala:77) at 
org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction
(Dataset.scala:3253) at 
org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>
(Dataset.scala:190) at 
org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows
(Dataset.scala:75) at 
org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql
(SparkSession.scala:641) at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0
(Native Method) at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
(Method.java:498) at 
py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke
(MethodInvoker.java:244) at 
py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke
(ReflectionEngine.java:357) at 
py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282) at 
py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod
(AbstractCommand.java:132) at 
py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute
(CallCommand.java:79) at 
py4j.GatewayConnection.run
(GatewayConnection.java:238) at 
java.lang.Thread.run
(Thread.java:748) 
18/08/09 09:31:42 WARN FileUtil: Failed to delete file or dir 
[/mnt/data/new.db/new_table/
_temporary/0/task_20180809093142_0002_m_000000/
.part-00000-55f3fe5c-51c2-4a0f-9f0c-dc673f9967b3-c000.snappy.parquet.crc]: 
it still exists.
18/08/09 09:31:42 WARN FileUtil: Failed to delete file or dir 
[/mnt/data/new.db/new_table/
_temporary/0/task_20180809093142_0002_m_000000/
part-00000-55f3fe5c-51c2-4a0f-9f0c-dc673f9967b3-c000.snappy.parquet]: 
it still exists.
```

If fails to rename and delete files/directories.

Directory structure:

```
# ls -lR new.db/
new.db/:
total 4
drwxrws--- 3 user_1 spark users 1024 Aug  9 09:31 new_table

new.db/new_table:
total 48
-rw-rw---- 1 user_1 spark users 39330 Aug  9 09:31 part-00000-55f3fe5c-51c2-4a0f-9f0c-dc673f9967b3-c000.snappy.parquet
drwxrws--- 3 user_1 spark users   512 Aug  9 09:31 _temporary

new.db/new_table/_temporary:
total 4
drwxrws--- 3 user_1 spark users 512 Aug  9 09:31 0

new.db/new_table/_temporary/0:
total 4
drwxr-sr-x 2 spark spark users 1024 Aug  9 09:31 task_20180809093142_0002_m_000000

new.db/new_table/_temporary/0/task_20180809093142_0002_m_000000:
total 44
-rw-rw---- 1 spark spark users 39330 Aug  9 09:31 part-00000-55f3fe5c-51c2-4a0f-9f0c-dc673f9967b3-c000.snappy.parquet
```

As you can see the directories up to **temporary/0** (inclusive) are owned by **user_1**, but then **task_** directories inside **temporary/0** are owned by **spark** user. Moreover the umask that was used to create those **task_** directories was 022, and not the desired 007.

If I can force **spark** user that creates those **task_** directories to actually use the correct umask, the issue would be resolved.

I appreciate and pointers and advise.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by wrong umask in the Worker process. The Worker process is started as a command via ssh in `$SPARK_HOME/sbin/slaves.sh` and .bashrc setting are not applied in this case (non-interactive session). The easiest solution is to set `umask 002` in `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh` as this is plain shell script sourced by all spark processes.